# How to get Quartz to read appsettings.json in .Net6 app

Tags: quartz-scheduler, appsettings

I am trying to configure Quartz scheduling (v3.7) using appsettings.json, but it appears not to be reading the configuration file.

My appsettings.json contains this:

```
{
  :
  "Quartz": {
    "quartz.plugin.xml.type": "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz",
    "quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames": "~/QuartzJobs.xml",
    "quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.connectionString": "--valid connection string--",
    "quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.provider": "SqlServer-20",
    "quartz.jobStore.type": "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
    "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType": "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
    "quartz.jobStore.dataSource": "quartzDataSource",
    "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix": "quartz.QRTZ_",
    "quartz.jobStore.clustered": "true",
    "quartz.scheduler.instanceId": "AUTO"
  }
}
```

My code contains this on startup:

```
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var services = new ServiceCollection();
             :
            services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Quartz")); // this section does exist
            services.AddQuartz();

        services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory>(provider =>
        {
            var jobFactory = new JobFactory(provider);
            return jobFactory;
        });

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var jobFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJobFactory>();

        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        _scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;
        :
        _scheduler.Start().Wait();
```

Certainly, none of my jobs in Quartz.xml run, and the scheduler has JobStoreClass as RAMJobStore, so I'm thinking it's not reading the appsettings ?